# Populate nested array with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a user schema as shown below and I'm trying to populate the live projects array but I can't figure out how to access it.

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  local: {
    email: String,
    username: String,
    password: String,
    liveProjects: [{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'liveProject'
    }]
  },
  google: {
    googleId: String,
    email: String,
    username: String,
    liveProjects: [{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'liveProject'
    }]
  }
});

const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

If it wasn't embedded I could just use

```
User.findById(id).populate('liveProjects').exec((err,projects)=>{});
```

But how do I get access to `'local.liveProjects'` or `'google.liveProjects'` so that I can populate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is just as simple as

```
User.findById(id).populate('local.liveProjects').exec((err,projects)=>{});
```

Answer (score 0):

User Schema Here

```
 `let UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    profile: {
        firstName: {type: String,required: true},
        lastName: {type: String,required: true},
        address1: {type: String},
        address2: {type: String},
        city: {type: String},
        state: {type: String},
        zip: {type: String},
        phone: {type: String,required: true},
        avatar:{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Avatar'},
        shippingAddress:{
            address1: {type: String},
            address2: {type: String},
            city: {type: String},
            state: {type: String},
            zip: {type: String}
        },
    },
    redemptionCards : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CardCodes' }]
});`
```

Logic to get RedemptionCards:-

```
User.findOne({ email }).populate("redemptionCards")
            .exec(function (err, user) {
                CardData.populate(user.redemptionCards, {path: 'redemptionCards',match: { _id: { $ne: null }}}, function (err, cards) {
    console.log(cards);
});
```

FYI - CardData is the Hardcoded JSON file. Hope this helps.

Comment: redemptionCards isn't listed in the schema?

Comment: Yes it is. Here you go:    redemptionCards : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CardCodes' }],

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. In the schema you posted redemptionCards does not appear as a primary object or sub object.

Comment: Thank you that makes more sense. Now if your redemptionCards array was contained within your profile object how would you populate it? This is my problem

Comment: I have added Code logic as well in-order to populate redemption cards up above.